# With Ajax i was able to change only first selection,

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I Got trouble with below coding, i couldn't able to make change with the option in selection, here i used `while` loop to get all listed in multiple selection box and used to Ajax to updated when i select, it works only for the first set of list, when i select other selection it implementing in first selection box

here is the code Ajax Code

```
$("#newqty").change(function(){ 

                var cartid=$('#cartid').val();

                //$('.form-select').ajaxSubmit(function(){

                var newqty = $(this).val(); 
                        var dataString = "newqty="+newqty+"&cartid="+cartid;

                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST", 
                                url: "changeprice.php", 
                                data: dataString,
                                async:false,    
                                })

                                 .done(function(result){ //on Ajax success
                                    alert("Selected"+dataString);

                                    //$("#show").html(result);  //alert user

                                    })


                        });
```

Here his coding for php

```
 <tr id='cartitems'><td><img style='height:90px; width:90px;' src='../e-comm/images/Lotus_truffles.jpg' alt='img'></td>
                    <td><h5 style='padding:10px; font-size:20px;'>Lotus Truffles</h5></td>
                     <td> 
                    <form method='post' class='form-select'>
                     <input type='text'  name='cartid' id='cartid' value=12 hidden>
                     <select name='newqty' id='newqty'><option value='qty'>Select Quantity</option>
                    <option selected='selected' value='12' select>12</option>
                    <option value='24'>24</option>
                    <option value='30'>30</option>
                    <option value='50'>50</option>
                    </select></form></td>

                    <td><h4 align='center' style='padding:20px;'>420 QAR</h4></td>
                 <td><a class='btn btn-primary' href='../e-comm/removecart.php?cartid=12'>delete</a></td>
                </tr>

          <tr id='cartitems'><td><img style='height:90px; width:90px;' src='../e-comm/images/white_digestive.jpg' alt='img'></td>
                <td><h5 style='padding:10px; font-size:20px;'>White Chocolate Digestive Truffles</h5></td>
                 <td> 
                <form method='post' class='form-select'>
                 <input type='text'  name='cartid' id='cartid' value=13 hidden>
                 <select name='newqty' id='newqty'><option value='qty'>Select Quantity</option>
                    <option selected='selected' value='12' select>12</option>
                    <option value='24'>24</option>
                    <option value='30'>30</option>
                    <option value='50'>50</option>
                    </select></form></td>

                    <td><h4 align='center' style='padding:20px;'>420 QAR</h4></td>
                 <td><a class='btn btn-primary' href='../e-comm/removecart.php?cartid=13'>delete</a></td>
                </tr>

          <tr id='cartitems'><td><img style='height:90px; width:90px;' src='../e-comm/images/Blueberry-Cheesecake.png' alt='img'></td>
                <td><h5 style='padding:10px; font-size:20px;'>Blueberrry Cheesecake</h5></td>
                 <td> 
                <form method='post' class='form-select'>
                 <input type='text'  name='cartid' id='cartid' value=14 hidden>
                 <select name='newqty' id='newqty'><option value='qty'>Select Quantity</option>
                    <option selected='selected' value='12' select>12</option>
                    <option value='24'>24</option>
                    <option value='30'>30</option>
                    <option value='50'>50</option>
                    </select></form></td>

                    <td><h4 align='center' style='padding:20px;'>420 QAR</h4></td>
                 <td><a class='btn btn-primary' href='../e-comm/removecart.php?cartid=14'>delete</a></td>
                </tr>

          <tr id='cartitems'><td><img style='height:90px; width:90px;' src='../e-comm/images/lotus_cheesecake.jpg' alt='img'></td>
                <td><h5 style='padding:10px; font-size:20px;'>Lotus Cheesecake</h5></td>
                 <td> 
                <form method='post' class='form-select'>
                 <input type='text'  name='cartid' id='cartid' value=15 hidden>
                 <select name='newqty' id='newqty'><option value='qty'>Select Quantity</option>
                    <option selected='selected' value='12' select>12</option>
                    <option value='24'>24</option>
                    <option value='30'>30</option>
                    <option value='50'>50</option>
                    </select></form></td>

                    <td><h4 align='center' style='padding:20px;'>540 QAR</h4></td>
                 <td><a class='btn btn-primary' href='../e-comm/removecart.php?cartid=15'>delete</a></td>
                </tr>
```

Here i want a form to be submit when my option is selected, Example when i select the 30 it should select and it should get the value of input box and selection as well. simply when i select any option it should submit form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you repeat the id (this should be unique). You can add a class to your selects:

```
<select name='newqty' id='newqty' class="yourClass"><option value='qty'>
```

And js:

```
$(document).on('change', '.yourClass', function() {...
```

I'd recommend to make the id's unique as well.

L.E: 
Change this too:

```
 <input type='text' class='cartClass' name='cartid' id='cartid' value=12 hidden>

$(document).on('change', '.yourClass', function() {...
       var cartid=$(this).siblings('.cartClass').val(); ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not complete, however, looking at the commented line in your javascript I am guessing you're replacing the DOM in your ajax call. This removes the event binding for the "change" trigger.

Try changing the following line:

```
$("#newqty").change(function(){
```

to this...

```
$(document).on('change', '#newqty', function() {
```

Comment: Let me try this one

Comment: No change, only the first one is working, when i click other list to it applying change on the first one not the which i selected

Comment: when i select other selection too it changing the first one

Answer (score 0):

This code really work handling my error

```
$(document).on('change', '#newqty', function() {

                    var cartid=$(this).siblings('#cartid').val();


                    var newqty = $(this).val(); 
                            var dataString = "newqty="+newqty+"&cartid="+cartid;

                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST", 
                                    url: "changeprice.php", 
                                    data: dataString,

                                    })

                                     .done(function(result){ //on Ajax success
                                        alert("Selected"+dataString);



                                        })

                            });
```

Here .siblings Prevented the inheriting same `carid` for all the form